# Why is my wifi ip address so different to other devices on my network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip

I have downloaded an app that look on my network and tells me the ip address of devices that are on it.

It seems to look for things in the range (192.168.80.0 to 192.168.80.255).

When my laptop is connected by ethernet, it falls within this range and is found by the app (along with many other devices in the building). But when I switch to wifi, its ip now begins 192.168.***70***.xx, and so doesn't get found by the app.

I don't understand ip addresses well. Could someone explain why the wifi ip address jumps outside of the range that the app is searching over?

(The app is Fing by the way).

Comment: What is your router model? Maybe router have two DHCP servers for wired and wireless networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your wifi model and manual.

Some wifi router provide feature like guest mode or network isolation which aims to provide better privacy and security.

e.g. You may allow your friend to use wifi for internet. But not necessary grant him access to your printer, NAS and PC.